# Rename plugin name in Wordpress Dashboard Menu

Tags: wordpress

I have tried a lot of suggestions on different posts here, but none of them seem to work for me.

I want to rename the name of a plugin on the dashboard menu on my Wordpress site. The name of the plugin is Sensei LMS and the path of the plugin folder is /plugins/sensei-lms.

I'd appreciate if someone helps me with some code that I can use to rename this. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

I've used [this tutorial](https://www.kevinleary.net/change-wordpress-plugin-menu-name/) in the past.

In your case, it would be:

```
function my_renamed_admin_menu_items() {
    global $menu;

    // Define your changes here
    $updates = array(
        "Sensei LMS" => array(
            'name' => 'New Menu Name'
        ),
        "Another Menu Name" => array(
            'name' => 'Another New Name'
        )
    );

    foreach ($menu as $k => $props) {

        // Check for new values
        $new_values = (isset($updates[$props[0]])) ? $updates[$props[0]] : false;
        if (!$new_values) continue;

        // Change menu name
        $menu[$k][0] = $new_values['name'];
    }
}
add_action('admin_init', 'my_renamed_admin_menu_items');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can rename your plugin by update in plugin_name.php file in your plugin directory.
you can also refer this url -for more info
https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/plugin-basics/header-requirements/

```
/*
 * Plugin Name: YOUR PLUGIN NAME
 */
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/inOFA.png)